# Problem with partitioning

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a problem trying to partition my hard drive.
I recently installed Ubuntu, to find out if I have a problem with the internet connection on my PC, since the Windows I was using couldn't connect to the local area.
After I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu I didn't select partitions and just installed it. Now I can't reinstall Windows since it is saying that all the hard drive is used on Ubuntu and that I have no free space left.

I tried creating partitions with GParted and the GParted live CD, but I can't find a way to create partitions since it says it is all being used. I am sure it's my fault since I didn't select root, swap and home, but I can't find a way to fix that.

In GParted I have the following information:

```
/dev/sda1  ext2   /boot                243.00Mib   74.84Mib used     170.16Mib aren't used
/dev/sda1  extended                    931.27Gib                      
/dev/sda5  lvm2pv ubuntu-vg            931.27Gib   931.23Gib used     44Mib aren't used
```

I hope the information helps. If you need any more info, please tell me.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you take a screenshot of Gparted and post it somewhere and give us the link

Comment: Since I am new here I cant post an image

Comment: yes I know, post it at any other website and give a link here

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you re-install ubuntu? if you have any data you could just back it up to a cloud like google drive and reinstall you system with the correct layout.
Sorry if this wasn't very helpful

```
              ~Rainbow Dash
```

Comment: No I dont have any data left from the pc before the format